# Apache Ignite Event Listener does not receive remote events when i setClientMode=true

Tags: ignite

Please see the below event listener code.

**Client Node attempting to be a listener:**

```
Ignition.setClientMode(true);
IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder ipFinder = new TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder();
ipFinder.setAddresses(Arrays.asList("127.0.0.1", "127.0.0.1:47500..47509"));
TcpDiscoverySpi spi = new TcpDiscoverySpi();
spi.setIpFinder(ipFinder);
cfg.setDiscoverySpi(spi);
cfg.setIncludeEventTypes(EventType.EVTS_CACHE);
IgnitePredicate<CacheEvent> rmtLsnr = (CacheEvent cacheEvent) -> {

if(cacheEvent.type() == EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_PUT) {
System.out.println(cacheEvent.name() + "," + cacheEvent.key());

}
            return true;
 };
Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(cfg);
ignite.events(ignite.cluster()
                .forCacheNodes(TestConstants.IgniteEventsTest.ORDER_CACHE))
                .remoteListen(null,rmtLsnr,EventType.EVTS_CACHE);
```

**Server Node hosting a cache:**

```
IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();

TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder ipFinder = new TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder();

ipFinder.setAddresses(Arrays.asList("127.0.0.1", "127.0.0.1:47500..47509"));

TcpDiscoverySpi spi = new TcpDiscoverySpi();

spi.setIpFinder(ipFinder);

cfg.setDiscoverySpi(spi);

Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(cfg);
CacheConfiguration cacheCfg = new CacheConfiguration(TestConstants.IgniteEventsTest.ORDER_CACHE);
cacheCfg.setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED);
cacheCfg.setWriteSynchronizationMode(FULL_ASYNC);
cacheCfg.setBackups(1);
```

**A remote client updating the cache:**

```
Ignition.setClientMode(true);
IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder ipFinder = new TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder();
ipFinder.setAddresses(Arrays.asList("127.0.0.1", "127.0.0.1:47500..47509"));
TcpDiscoverySpi spi = new TcpDiscoverySpi();
spi.setIpFinder(ipFinder);
cfg.setDiscoverySpi(spi);

Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(cfg);
CacheConfiguration cacheCfg = new CacheConfiguration(TestConstants.IgniteEventsTest.ORDER_CACHE);
cacheCfg.setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED);
cacheCfg.setWriteSynchronizationMode(FULL_SYNC);
IgniteCache<Integer, Order> 
clientOrderCache  = ignite.getOrCreateCache(cacheCfg);

in a loop...

clientOrderCache.put(key , order);
```

My observation is that when ClientMode=true on the event listener we dont receive events.
Please let me know if its mandatory for an event listener to be in server mode to listen for events? Or is it something wrong i am doing ?

Answer (score 1):

You did not define the local listener (it's `null` in your code). Remote filter is always executed where the event was fired, in case of cache update it's one of the server nodes. If you create a local listener as well, all events for which remote filter returns `true` will be propagated to the client.

Refer to the CacheEventsExample [1] for the code sample.

[1] https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/examples/datagrid/CacheEventsExample.java

Comment: Hi @Valentin, I have created an instance of  IgniteBiPredicate<UUID, CacheEvent> and passed as local listener however did not get any event. Any advice please.

Comment: Try to enable events on all nodes (especially on server node).

Comment: I am running Ignite server by clicking on ignite.bat file and copied jar file in lib folder. While both client are running in eclipse so using the same code base again. Same question I have asked as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42729647/apache-ignite-cache-event-registration-not-working. sorry to duplicate the question.

Comment: You should run server node with proper configuration. Use `ignite.bat <path\to\config.xml>` command.

Comment: Thanks. It works fine when I use ignite.bat <path\to\config.xml> command. Is it possible if we can pass all configuration using Java only? i.e. Start Ignite server Node as a Java standalone program?

Comment: Yes, you can create a program that will invoke `Ignition.start` with proper configuration. Please refer to examples provided with Ignite, a lot of things can become much clearer.